# Executing shell script using Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins

I would want to execute the shell script using Jenkins.

For example, I have a shell script MakeTest.sh which is on the server "test1.test2.net" location "/home/rt", how would I execute it? My Jenkins and script to be executed are in different servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using git, you can download the file into the workspace of your job.
After you just have to launch the script ./MakeTest.sh